# Using SQL Server, GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm studying database design and architecture and i've come across a question that i can't complete.
Here it is: "List all the cities of Canada, followed by their population expressed as a percentage of the country's population."

My tables are:

`Country`, `City` and `CountryLanguage`.

The query i issued, thus far, is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City.Name,
                CAST(City.Population as float)/CAST(Country.Population as float)*100 as Percentage
FROM City,Country
Where City.CountryCode='CAN' and 
      Country.Population >0
```

However, i'm still getting multiple Names and percentages that go over 100.
Is there any aggregate function that i can use in order to use the GROUP BY clause to group the names?

Comment: Why do you have `FROM City,Country`? This is old-style join syntax which you shouldn't be using for precisely the reason (or at least part of the reason) you're having a problem: you forgot your join criteria, so this is a cross join! You're going to have figures for cities in countries they don't belong to. [Please read this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a way to relate City to Country. Currently you are getting a cross join, so I predict you have results for the following Canadian cities (but in the wrong country):

- Toronto, Japan
- Lethbridge, China
- Winnipeg, South Africa
- Saskatoon, Russia
- Vancouver, Nepal
- Halifax, Sweden
- Montreal, France
- etc. etc.

Here is a query using proper, modern INNER JOIN syntax, relating City and Country by CountryCode (an assumption I made from your existing query).

```
SELECT City.Name, Percentage = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), City.Population) 
    / NULLIF(Country.Population,0) * 100.0
 FROM dbo.City
 INNER JOIN dbo.Country 
 ON City.CountryCode = Country.CountryCode
 WHERE Country.CountryCode = 'CAN' AND Country.Population > 0;
```

Note that I use `NULLIF` in the denominator in case SQL Server decides to attempt to put a population of 0 there, which can happen and be processed before such a row is eliminated by the `WHERE` clause (see [this Connect item for more details](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)).

Please read [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to see why you should never use `FROM table1, table2` syntax (most of your problem is based on the mistake this syntax allows!).

Comment: +1 . . . But there does happen to be a Montreal in France (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montr%C3%A9al,_Aude).

Comment: @Gordon Ha! Did not know that, but I'm not shocked.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #Country 
(id int identity(1,1),
Name nvarchar(100),
Population float 
 )

create table #City 
(id int identity(1,1),
Name nvarchar(100),
Population float,
CountryId int  

 )


insert into  #City  select 'ABC', 1000,1
insert into  #City  select 'EFG', 2000,1
insert into  #City  select 'HIJ', 3000,1
insert into  #City  select 'KLM', 5000,1
insert into  #City  select 'XYX', 12000,2


insert into  #Country  select 'Canda', 11000  
insert into  #Country  select 'US', 12000

select C.Name, round(C.Population/Cn.Population*100,2) AS [% population] from  #City C
inner join #Country Cn On C.CountryId = Cn.id
wheRe C.CountryId =1

drop table #Country 
drop table #City
```